# SQL Rank selection oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

I have an issue such that my table looks like below;

`REC_ID |    Year  |   status |
-------|-----------|----------|
 123   |    2016   |      OA  |
 123   |    2017   |      CC  |`

My query should check if for rec_id ? if

1. There is a record for 2016 where the status is OA then pick that row.
2. There is a record for 2016 where the status is any-other status (not OA) and no record exists for 2017 then pick that row (2016 row).
3. There is a record for 2016 with any-other status (not OA) and a record exists for 2017 then pick the record for 2017

so in the above example the 2016 record should get picked up.

`REC_ID |    Year  |   status |
-------|-----------|----------|
 456   |    2016   |      OP  |`

in this example since there is only one record the 2016 record should get picked up.

`REC_ID |    Year  |   status |
-------|-----------|----------|
 789   |    2016   |      OM  |
 789   |    2017   |      CC  |`

In this last example since there are two records and the 2016 is NOT OA then the 2017 record should get picked up.

I have tried ranking them but that doesn't work and have tried doing something like below but both records get picked up.

```
 SELECT CASE
WHEN (STATUS = 'OA'
    AND YEAR              = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
    AND ?= REC_ID)
    OR ((SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE ?= REC_ID
      AND YEAR = TO_CHAR(add_months(sysdate, 12), 'YYYY' ))= 0)
    THEN TABLE.STATUS
    ELSE
      (SELECT STATUS
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE ?= REC_ID
      AND YEAR       = TO_CHAR(add_months(sysdate, 12), 'YYYY' )
      )
  END from TABLE WHERE ?= REC_ID ;
```

Comment: The rules seem insufficient. What if there are only rows for 2016, no row for 2017, no row has status OA, but there is more than one row? For example 2016 CC and 2016 AD. Which of these rows should be chosen? Also, if no row with 2016 and OA, but more than one row with 2017 - WHICH row with 2017 should be chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-wording the ranking:

1. 2016 AND status = 'OA'
2. 2017
3. 2016

The query with `ROW_NUMBER` to pick the best match per `rec_id`:

```
select rec_id, year, status
from
(
  select 
    rec_id, year, status,
    row_number() OVER (partition by rec_id
               order by case 
                 when year = 2016 and status = 'OA' then 1 
                 when year = 2017 then 2
                 else 3
               end) as rn
  from mytable
  where year in (2016, 2017)
)
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query, which suggests using `row_number()`.  I think you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by rec_id
                                order by (case when year = 2016 and status = 'OA' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         year desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
      where year in (2016, 2017)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```